# Plotly cannot reach orca server when exporting svg file

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to export a plotly histogram to an svg file. This works nicely until I try to handle a large number of data points. The code below works for 1000000 simulated data points, but breaks for 10000000 points.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.io as pio

import numpy as np

# simulate small input data: this works
# data_1 = list(np.random.randint(0, 2**63, 1_000_000))
# data_2 = list(np.random.randint(0, 2**63, 1_000_000))

# simulate larger input data: this works
data_1 = list(np.random.randint(0, 2**63, 10_000_000))
data_2 = list(np.random.randint(0, 2**63, 10_000_000))

# assemble two histograms and plot them into one figure
g1 = go.Histogram(x=data_1, opacity=0.75)
g2 = go.Histogram(x=data_2, opacity=0.75)
data = [g1, g2]
figure = go.Figure(data=data)

# write the plot as html, this works
plotly.offline.plot(figure, auto_open=True, filename="/tmp/foo.html")

# writing the plot as svg (or png) file doesn't work
pio.write_image(figure, "/tmp/foo.svg")
```

If run with 10000000 simulated data points I get the following error message (full stacktrace below):

```
ValueError: 
For some reason plotly.py was unable to communicate with the
local orca server process, even though the server process seems to be running.
```

The problem is: With my real dataset I cannot simply reduce the number of points. Does anyone know, what is going on here and how to fix this?

It looks a little bit like the orca server timing out, because computation takes too long, but the timeout duration for the server is (per default) set to `None` i.e. no timeout. I also tried to change the port of the sever (as suggested [here](https://community.plot.ly/t/use-plotly-offline-to-save-chart-as-image-file/408/37)), but that did not help.

---

### Additional information

I am using plotly 3.3.0 and orca 1.1.1. My orca config (`print(pio.orca.config)`) looks like this:

```
orca configuration
------------------
    executable: orca
    port: None
    timeout: None
    default_width: None
    default_height: None
    default_scale: 1
    default_format: png
    mathjax: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js
    topojson: None
    mapbox_access_token: None

constants
---------
    plotlyjs: /home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/package_data/plotly.min.js 
    config_file: /home/m00am/.plotly/.orca
```

#### Full stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 356, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 986, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 649, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 347, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 356, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 986, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/io/_orca.py", line 1305, in to_image
    height=height)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/io/_orca.py", line 1201, in request_image_with_retrying
    response = requests.post(server_url + '/', data=json_str)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 110, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 473, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bar.py", line 107, in <module>
    distribution_comparison()
  File "bar.py", line 97, in distribution_comparison
    pio.write_image(figure, "/tmp/foo.png")
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/io/_orca.py", line 1492, in write_image
    validate=validate)
  File "/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/io/_orca.py", line 1322, in to_image
    """.format(info=status_str))
ValueError: 
For some reason plotly.py was unable to communicate with the
local orca server process, even though the server process seems to be running.

Please review the process and connection information below:

orca status
-----------
    state: running
    executable: /home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/bin/orca
    version: 1.1.1
    port: 40887
    pid: 3277
    command: ['/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/bin/orca', 'serve', '-p', '40887', '--plotly', '/home/m00am/miniconda3/envs/my_conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/package_data/plotly.min.js', '--graph-only', '--mathjax', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js']
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a timeout issue, unfortunately the `timeout` parameter in orca's configuration has nothing to do with the request timeout, which seems to be hardcoded in the [server sources](https://github.com/plotly/orca/blob/master/src/app/server/constants.js). You could try building orca with a bigger `requestTimeout` or submitting an issue at the repo.